# composer installation for laravel laravel

Tags: php, xampp

I am installing composer for laravel installation.but when it want php.exe file i coudn't find it in c:/xampp/php folder.I set up my path variable c:/xampp/php but it is still not working.help me guys.

Comment: This is more related to [tag:XAMPP] than Laravel and Composer.

Comment: The folder is correct. Probabily something fail during the installation process. Did you look at the antivirus log ? I heard that xampp had some problems with Kaspersky.

Answer (score 1):

If xampp has correctly installed, but you are failing to run PHP it is more than possible that you don't have PHP set in your environment paths.

To set this go to;

```
Start > right click computer > properties > Advanced system settings > Environment Variables.
```

Under System variables find a variable named **PATH**, highlight then click Edit... Append the absolute path to your root PHP folder, this could either be xampps located in.

```
c:/xampp/php/
```

Press Ok, once you've finished; close down any command prompt windows you may have open. Re-open command prompt and run **php -v**. Hopefully at this point PHP has responded with it's version and license information.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `xampp` properly installed.

If you add `c:/xampp/php` to your `PATH` while you have a console open, you need to open another console, in order for the `PATH` to be updated.

Comment: cornelb,can u explain how can i update my path and i think xampp is installed properly cause i can work with this but i coudn't find php.exe file.i am stuck.

Comment: You could not find the file, or it does not work when you type 'php' inside the command prompt?

Comment: i opened xampp/php folder and there is no file named php.exe.

Comment: what xampp version? Please search for `php.exe` in all folders

Answer (score 0):

i think I have that problem one day, i solved uninstalling xampp server and reinstalling it, but when xampp ask you wich folder to install you need to create a new folder:

```
C://new folder/xampp/.......
```

If you install/uninstall multiples xampp or wampp versions for some reasons create storage info in the xampp folder, so creating a new folder solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this path:

c:/xampp/php/php.exe

Answer (score 0):

PATH should be a directory, not a file, so you should set it to "c:\xampp\php\", other than"c:\xampp\php\php.exe"